# Replacing nulls by fillna still returns nulls in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, fillna

I'm trying to replace nulls in few columns of pandas dataframe by fillna.

```
df["A"].fillna("Global", inplace=True)
df["B"].fillna("Global", inplace=True)
df["C"].fillna("Global", inplace=True)
df["D"].fillna("Global", inplace = True)
```

The nulls don't seem to be replaced completely as `df.isnull().sum()`
still returns non-zero values for columns A,B,C and D.

I have also tried the following, it doesn't seem to make a difference.

```
df["A"] = df["A"].fillna("Global", inplace=True)
df["B"] = df["B"].fillna("Global", inplace=True)
df["C"] = df["C"].fillna("Global", inplace=True)
df["D"] = df["D"].fillna("Global", inplace=True)
```

Following is my Sample data which contains NAN

```
id                 A        B                             D
630940            NaN       NaN         ...             NaN   
630941            NaN       NaN         ...             NaN
```

Comment: Can you show your sample data ?

Comment: @Wen - Added the sample data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inplace `fillna` does not work on `pd.Series` columns because they return a copy, and the copy is modified, leaving the original untouched.

Why not just do -

```
df.loc[:, 'A':'D'] = df.loc[:, 'A':'D'].fillna('Global')
```

Or,

```
df.loc[:, ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D']] = df.loc[:, ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D']].fillna('Global')
```